# Driver info: driver.version: unknown when Switching from Selenium Standalone 2.X to 3.X

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Standalone Server on OS X together with facebook/php-webdriver. I am trying to run a PHP script using **ChromeDriver 2.28 which is up to date.** If I launch selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0, my script works perfectly. If I launch selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1, my script dies with the message Driver info: driver.version: unknown. I have tried to add  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver in my Java command but it does not change anything. Chrome, ChromeDriver and the selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar are in the Applications directory and I launch my Java command line from that directory.

Comment: Are you using chromedriver version 2.28?

Comment: You should add some examples, what are you running and the stack-trace error. See if my answer from here helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032960/unknown-option-dwebdriver-chrome-driver-when-running-selenium-server-standalon

Comment: Try using latest chromedriver

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chrome Driver, with regards to logs. In the terminal window where selenium Server is running, I don't get any error, no exception is generated. In the terminal where I run my PHP command I get : Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
System info: host: 'iMac', ip: XXXXX', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: driver.version:: unknown

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140045/selenium-remotewebdriver-connection-to-selenium-standalone-server-fail-driver

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the answer, it's an issue between facebook/php-webdriver and the new selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar. With the previous version of selenimum server, the \Facebook\WebDriver\RemoteRemoteDriver::createBySessionID() was creating a new session when the session id passed as an argument was null whereas it now fails with the message Driver info: driver.version:unknown. I don't think it can be considered as a bug apart from the fact that the error it triggers does not help to determine its origin.